# How to change the resources allocated to a container at run time?

Tags: resources, docker

I am aware that I can limit the resources allocated to a container while provisioning using docker with the `-c` and `-m` flags for CPU and memory.

However, is there a way I can change these allocated resources to containers dynamically (after they have been provisioned) and without redeploying the same container with changed resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not at present no - There is a desire to see someone implement it though: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6323

Comment: This is now implemented. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/

Answer (score 29):

At the time (Docker v1.11.1) has the command `docker update` ([view docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)). With this you can change allocated resources on the fly.

```
Usage:  docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Update configuration of one or more containers

  --blkio-weight          Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000
  --cpu-shares            CPU shares (relative weight)
  --cpu-period            Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
  --cpu-quota             Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
  --cpuset-cpus           CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
  --cpuset-mems           MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
  --help                  Print usage
  --kernel-memory         Kernel memory limit
  -m, --memory            Memory limit
  --memory-reservation    Memory soft limit
  --memory-swap           Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: '-1' to enable unlimited swap
  --restart               Restart policy to apply when a container exits
```

Answer (score 2):

That could be coming for docker 1.10 or 1.11 (Q1 2016): [PR 15078](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078) is implementing (Dec. 2015) support for changing resources (including CPU) both for stopped *and running* container.

Update 2016: it is [part of docker 1.10](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/f064b9941c0c6070740339971a0bb59b4fe6195f) and documented in [`docker update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) ([PR 15078](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078)).

> We decided to allow to set what we called resources, which consists of cgroup thingies for now, hence the following [PR #18073](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/18073).
>   The only allowed mutable elements of a container are in HostConfig and precisely in Resources (see the [struct](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/runconfig/hostconfig.go#L169)).

```
resources := runconfig.Resources{
        BlkioWeight:       *flBlkioWeight,
        CpusetCpus:        *flCpusetCpus,    <====
        CpusetMems:        *flCpusetMems,    <====
        CPUShares:         *flCPUShares,     <====
        Memory:            flMemory,
        MemoryReservation: memoryReservation,
        MemorySwap:        memorySwap,
        KernelMemory:      kernelMemory,
        CPUPeriod:         *flCPUPeriod,
        CPUQuota:          *flCPUQuota,
    }
```

> - The command should be <del>`set`</del> (in the end: `update`).
> - The allowed changes are passed as flags : e.g. `--memory=1Gb --cpushare=…` (as this PR does).
> - There is one flag for each attribute of the `Resources` struct (and no more, no less).

Note that making changes via `docker set` should persist.
I.e., those changes would be permanent (updated in the container's JSON)