# Is it possible to increase the memory limit of a docker container after it is started?

Tags: docker, memory

To set up memory limit for a docker container we can use the  `-m` flag, so I started a container with a 2GB of memory limit using the `-m` flag, now I want to know if it is possible to increase the memory limit of this running container ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192770/how-to-change-the-resources-allocated-to-a-container-at-run-time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with the help of `docker update` command

```
docker update --help

Usage:  docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Update configuration of one or more containers

Options:
      --blkio-weight uint16        Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000, or 0 to disable (default 0)
      --cpu-period int             Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
      --cpu-quota int              Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
      --cpu-rt-period int          Limit the CPU real-time period in microseconds
      --cpu-rt-runtime int         Limit the CPU real-time runtime in microseconds
  -c, --cpu-shares int             CPU shares (relative weight)
      --cpus decimal               Number of CPUs
      --cpuset-cpus string         CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --cpuset-mems string         MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --kernel-memory bytes        Kernel memory limit
  -m, --memory bytes               Memory limit
      --memory-reservation bytes   Memory soft limit
      --memory-swap bytes          Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: '-1' to enable unlimited swap
      --restart string             Restart policy to apply when a container exits
```

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)

Following is my docker version and machine details

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```